# how to automatically resize image to screen size from alt attribute and not src

Tags: javascript, image, function, resize

i have downloaded an image scrollpane which changes the background images. i want to make the images get resized automatically at screen size.. to do this i used this html line
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
but then i realised that this line wont work on my case because the scrollpane works a little bit differently.

to be more specific, the scrollpane will use as background image the alt attribute of the img tag and for the thumbnails of the image it will use the src attribute of the img tag.

```
<div class="wrapper thumbs_wrapper"> 
        <div class="thumbs"> 
            <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg"/> 
            <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg"/> 
        </div> 
</div>
```

so if i add this line here

```
<img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
```

there wont be any change to the background image but only to the thumbnail.. is there any way to resize the image from the alt attribute?

i simply want to grab the img from the alt attribute and resize it with a javascript function and set the width and height to 100%.

i have written this function but it doesn't work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resize()
{
    var element = document.getElementById('imgg');
    var attr = element.getAttribute(alt);
    attr.width = '100%';
    attr.height = '100%';
}
</script>

<img id="imgg" onload="resize()" src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" height='' width=''/>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you put up a jsFiddle, or at least show a mockup of what you're trying to do? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. But I do know that you can't change the width and height of an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var browserWidth= $(window).width();
    $('.fullscreen').css({
        height: browserHeight ,
        width: browserWidth
    });
})
</script>
  <img id="imgg" class="fullscreen" src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" height='' width=''/>
```